# Deploying new dropin in WSO2IS without restart

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to deploy new dropins into WSO2 IS without restarting whole application? I have to test some new authenticator but our development environment is not the fastest in the world, so im looking for the possibility of reload jar's without restarting WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the first time you deploy the authenticator to dropins, you have to restart the IS server to get the changes applied.

But if you want to make changes to existing class files of the authenticator that is already deployed and get the changes into the application without restarting, you can use the hotswap mechanism during a debug session.
Refer: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes

I'll mention how to do this in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm sure that this should be possible with other IDEs as well.

1. Configure remote debugging https://medium.com/p/c0e828abd700
2. Open your authenticator code in IntelliJ idea and set the remote debugger there
3. Go to the class file you have done new changes
4. Right click -> Click the "Compile And Reload File"
   [image]
5. Once it's succesfull you can see something similar as follows

[image]